# Delete record not working in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have code in which check condition then execute following sequence:

-- Delete records from table

-- Upload CSV file into Oracle form data block

-- Upload button label changed

When I press upload button then form executing query and did not run

**CODE:**

```
declare
 v_label  pls_integer;

begin

 v_label := regexp_replace(Get_Item_Property('Upload',label),'(\D)')+1;

 IF ( :WE_GROUP.FILE IS NOT NULL ) AND :WE_GROUP.DISPLAY IS NULL THEN

    DELETE FROM we_group_hof_k;
    commit;
    execute_query;

    CSV_UPLOAD_HOF;
    commit;

   Set_Item_Property('Upload',label,'Upload'||' ['||1||']');

   :WE_GROUP.FILE := NULL;

END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `COMMIT`, use `COMMIT_FORM`.